# Mounting local volumes to docker container

Tags: macos, docker

Edited for clarity

I run the following run command

```
docker run -d -P -v /users/username/app:/app contname
```

This resulsts in the following when i inspect the container

```
"HostConfig": {
        "Binds": [
            "/users/username/app:/app"
        ],

"Volumes": {
        "/app": "/users/username/app",
        "/app": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/214a16c3678f93cbadb7e7b7d56b5f26b66a34c6d9bb89ade23b16e386a12212"
    },
```

But when i ssh into the container, i can see that app is empty.

Is my assumption that there should be the files from my host machine correct?

Answer (score 0):

Boot2docker automatically mounts your home directory into the virtualbox boot2docker VM not the container. You still need to add `-v /users/username/app:/app` to your docker run command.

When you add the Volume command to your docker file you are declaring a volume to be created by the container. This volume is mounted at `/var/lib/docker/volumes` on the host VM. These volumes can only be shared by passing --volumes-from to the docker run command. When you pass the -v switch you creating a volume using a specified location on the host file system.

Comment: so i don't have to specify volumes if i just want to mirrow my dev folder? All i should do, is run the container with the -v flag and the folder i want to mirror?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer to make it more clear. -v is also a means of specifying a volume, it just maps a specific directory as that volume.